# Multiple Popup from markers

Tags: leaflet

How to keep multiple pop-ups open after clicking on multiple markers? By default, Leaflet seems to close the previous pop-up.

For example, please see

```
https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/
```

There are 6 orange markers. When any of them is clicked, a popup opens. When the next one is clicked, a new popup opens and the prev one is closed. I'd like to keep them open, until manually closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option [autoClose](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#popup-autoclose) for that ...

and you will need [bindPopup](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#layer-bindpopup)(Popup) instead of bindPopup(String)